# How can I set a default date format for all backend fields in OctoberCms?

Tags: octobercms

When I create a date field in OctoberCMS by default it is formatted as m/d/Y but I want to use d/m/Y instead.

Fortunately OctoberCMS allows date widgets to format the date before displaying using the 'format' attribute so this partially solves the problem.

This 'format' parameter is not available in all widgets, for example I want to create a 'list filter' which does not have it so I cannot change the date format. (https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#filter-daterange)

Is there a way I can set the default format to be used by all elements?

[image]

Here is my config_list.yaml file:

```
title: Properties
modelClass: DP\Properties\Models\Property
list: $/dp/properties/models/property/columns.yaml
recordUrl: 'dp/properties/properties/update/:id'
noRecordsMessage: 'backend::lang.list.no_records'
recordsPerPage: 20
showSetup: true
showCheckboxes: true
defaultSort:
    column: updated_at
    direction: asc
toolbar:
    buttons: list_toolbar
    search:
        prompt: 'backend::lang.list.search_prompt'
filter: config_filter.yaml
```

And an here is a part of the config_filter.yaml file

```
...
    updated_at:
        label: 'Updated'
        type: daterange
        conditions: created_at >= ':after' AND created_at <= ':before'
        format: d-m-Y
...
```

And the controller

```
class Properties extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [
        'Backend\Behaviors\ListController',
        'Backend\Behaviors\FormController',
        'Backend\Behaviors\ReorderController'
    ];

    public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';
    public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';
    public $reorderConfig = 'config_reorder.yaml';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        BackendMenu::setContext('DP.Properties', 'main-menu-item');
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code in list.yaml and controller.php please.

Comment: @PettisBrandon just updated my question with list and controller, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

In October the default date format is tied to the locale of the system. (within the backend).

To change the default date format, click on your user avatar in the top right and click "Back-end preferences". The default locale will be set at English (United States). You can change this to whatever you want. English (United Kingdom) should resolve the date format default. But I believe that it is only the US who use the m/d/Y format

Comment: although this is true for administrators having admin rights, this is not available to the rest of the groups. I found out that you can change it for all users by editing 'backendTimezone' attribute in /config/cms.php' file

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default timezone used by all backend forms by editing 'backendTimezone' attribute in /config/cms.php' file and adding your timezone.